# Autocopy selected text to clipboard, as in PuTTy

Tags: windows, clipboard

Can you tell such a tool for windows, that lets you to autocopy selected text to clipboard, as in PuTTy or terminal emulators. But it must copy text from any other app too.

Thanks!

Comment: Please ask this at superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with AutoHotkey. Look at [this thread](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic5439.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for Windows utility to make autocopy you can check [Click cutter](http://clickcutter.com)